# Remove Vowels from more than first word

Tags: c++11

Program compiles, runs, and works.

Big issue:

It only works for the first word of a sentence.

EXAMPLE:

"Welcome to the jungle" results in "wlcm" rather than "wlcm t th jngl".

Small Issue:

There's a "1" appearing between input and output when it runs. How can I get rid of that? I think it's from this, but I'm not positive:

```
{
    withVowel.erase(i, 1);
    length = int(withVowel.length());
}
```

WHOLE CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


void removeVowel(string&);       // Removes vowels from input string.
string withVowel;                // Will be used to read user input. 

int main ()
{   

    const string SENTINEL = "0";        // Sentinel value. 

    // Request input string unless SENTINEL is entered.  

    cout << "Enter a word or series of words." << '\n';
    cout << "Or, enter " << SENTINEL << " to quit." << '\n' << endl;
    cin >> withVowel;

    // In case of SENTINEL:

    while (withVowel == SENTINEL)
    {
        cout << '\n' << "***" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Run loop.

    removeVowel(withVowel);

    // Display the string without vowels.

    cout << "The word(s) entered reflecting only consonants: " << withVowel << endl;

    return 0;
}

    void removeVowel(string& withVowel)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int length = int(withVowel.length());
        while (i < length)
    {
        if (withVowel.at(i) == 'a' || 
            withVowel.at(i) == 'A' || 
            withVowel.at(i) == 'e' || 
            withVowel.at(i) == 'E' ||
            withVowel.at(i) == 'i' || 
            withVowel.at(i) == 'I' || 
            withVowel.at(i) == 'o' || 
            withVowel.at(i) == 'O' || 
            withVowel.at(i) == 'u' ||
            withVowel.at(i) == 'U')

            {
                withVowel.erase(i, 1);
                length = int(withVowel.length());
            }
            else i++; 
        }

    // Display the string without vowels.   

    cout << removeVowel << endl;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getline(cin, withVowel);` instead of `cin >> withVowel;`

Also replace `while` with `if` in main(). 
And don't forget to upvote and accept answers=)

Comment: So perfect, thank you!! I tried using getline before but in the wrong place so that was a no go. Do you have any idea how to get rid of the "1" being an output??

Comment: delete "cout << removeVowel << endl;"

Comment: Geesh. Thanks. It's so much more simple than it all seems :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with only getting the first word is being you're using `cin >> withVowel;`, which will stop reading input as soon as it encounters white space. Try using `std::getine(cin, withVowel);` instead.

If at all possible, I would avoid manipulating the string in place, and just copy things to the output if they're not vowels.

```
std::remove_copy_if(withVowel.begin(), withVowel.end(), 
    [](char c) { return c == 'a' || c == 'A' || 
                        c == 'e' || c == 'E' || 
                        c == 'i' ...;});
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'm not sure what you mean, though. Are you suggesting I replace the if statement with that code?

Comment: What a uncomely code. Maybe something like: `{for(x : {'a','A',...}) if (c == x) return true;...` or `return find(begin(tab),end(tab),c) != end(tab)`?